# How to find duplicate rows and assign an ID in a new column

Tags: python

I have a `dataframe` that looks something like this:

```
col_0        col_1          col_2        col_3
Type_1       data1          data2        data3
Type_2       data2          data1        data3
Type_3       data4
Type_4       data4          data5
```

Notice that `type_1` and `type_2` rows are still duplicates, just that the values are placed in different columns. Also, `col_0` should not be included in checking for duplicates.

So I want to add a new column, with a new name or `ID`, that has the same `ID` for duplicate rows. The desired output would look something like this:

```
col_0        col_1          col_2        col_3     col_4
Type_1       data1          data2        data3     1
Type_2       data2          data1        data3     1
Type_3       data4                                 2
Type_4       data4          data5                  3
```

Comment: What is the data-type of col1/2/3 ?
Also, how do you handle missing values?

Comment: They are all string data. Missing values should be ignored because if one row has a missing value, the other one does not.

Comment: The basic idea goes something like this:
1. Combine values from col1/2/3 into a new column (say `col_combined`)
2. Maintain a hash-map from combined-value to column-id
3. Use this hash-map to populate the col4

Comment: you could put them all into a temp buffer, sort them all, compare for equallity, update the id's of the unsorted data